# Symfony : why am I not allowed to combine "type" with "defaults" in routing.yml

Tags: php, symfony

**Short version of the question :** Symfony's error message
explains that I cannot use the `type` key in conjunction with
`defaults`, I can only  use with `resources` (see details below).
Why is it so ? How can I fix it ?

**Detailed version :**

Here is the exact sequence of what I did in Symfony :

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition sym-book/ '~2.5'
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=MiddleMan/BookBundle --format=yml
```

Edit the contents of `src/MiddleMan/BookBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` to

```
middle_man_book_example:
    path:     /example
    defaults: { _controller: MiddleManBookBundle:Lucky:number }
    type: annotation
```

In directory `src/MiddleMan/BookBundle/Controller`,
rename `DefaultController.php` to `LuckyController.php`, and edit its contents to

```
namespace MiddleMan\BookBundle\Controller;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Type `localhost:8000/example/lucky/number` in my browser.

The error message is as follows :

```
The "type" key for the route definition "middle_man_book_example" in 
"/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Math_Software/Symfony_stuff/sym-book/src/MiddleMan/BookBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" 
is unsupported. It is only available for imports in combination with 
the "resource" key in 
/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Math_Software/Symfony_stuff/sym-book/src/MiddleMan/BookBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml (
which is being imported from "/Users/ewandelanoy/Documents/Math_Software/Symfony_stuff/sym-book/app/config/routing.yml")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `type: annotation` you don't need, and, actually, must not, to store `defaults` section in routing.yml. Defaults section would be configured for each route in its own annotation, route annotation would look like:

```
/**
 * Sample route
 * @Route("/{id}", name="sample-route-name", defaults={"id" = 1})
 * //defaults section is there to provide default values
 *
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"}) // not actually needed, default - GET
 */
```

And yml routing configuration would look like:

```
sample_bundle_routing:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /some_prefix/
```

**UPD**
This yml config should be put in main `routing.yml`. But you could use another variant. In main `routing.yml` put this:

```
sample_bundle_routing:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

Then in the `routing.yml` that you put in main `routing.yml` as a resource you can write:

```
sample_bundle_routing:
    resource: "@YourBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /some_prefix/
```

I have a question: why do you need to use both yml and annotation routing config? I mean that you write in your comment below: "But I need to edit the routing.yml file in my directory also, to give the controller name and action method name.". If you use annotation routing type - you could do it there no need to do configuration for annotation routing in yml. I mean: you do routing either as annotations for each action or as strings in bundle/main `routing.yml`, not both at the same time! If you use annotation routing, the only thing you need to put in yml - is where to look for routing config (in my example it was `"@YourBundle/Controller/"` path).

Comment: This yml routing configuration you wrote should be put in app/config/routing.yml, not in my bundle directory, right ? But I need to edit the routing.yml file in my directory also, to give the controller name and action method name.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, added update as answer for your question in comment. See it.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I think I get it now : if you use annotation, Symfony will scan all controller classes and actions and look for the unique one corresponding to the route given to the browser.

Comment: I'd better say that sf does not scan all(!) controller classes, it scans only that classes which lays under path provided in routing.yml - in `resource` option for that route parts that has `type: annotation`.